# Postgresql Timestamp validation

Tags: postgresql, validation, date

Why is this function not working? It is supposed to validate timestamp. Timestamp in format YYYYMMDDHHMISS as an argument to the function. Please advise.

```
/*Function for validating argument passed as timestamp */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_is_valid_yyyymmddhhmiss2(
    i_yyyymmddhhmiss character,
    OUT o_return_cd smallint,
    OUT o_return_msg character varying,
    OUT o_is_valid_yyyymmddhhmiss character)
    RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE 
    AS $function$

    DECLARE
    v_Is_Valid_YYYYMMDDHHMISS  VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y';
    v_Return_Cd  SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
    v_Return_Msg  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'SUCCESS';
    v_Output_Txt  VARCHAR(3200);
    v_Num        INTEGER;

    v_Return_Cd_saved  SMALLINT;
    v_Return_Msg_saved  VARCHAR(255);

BEGIN

    BEGIN
/* Timestamp validation */
        PERFORM to_timestamp(i_yyyymmddhhmiss)::timestamp;
        v_Num := 1;
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_Num := 0;
    END;

        IF (v_Num = 1) THEN
            v_Return_Cd := '0' ;
            v_Return_Msg := 'Date Timestamp validation is successful';

            v_Is_Valid_YYYYMMDDHHMISS := 'Y';

        ELSE
            v_Return_Cd := '20003' ;
            v_Return_Msg := 'Date Timestamp validation is NOT successful';

            v_Is_Valid_YYYYMMDDHHMISS := 'F';

        END IF;

        O_IS_VALID_YYYYMMDDHHMISS := v_Is_Valid_YYYYMMDDHHMISS;
        O_RETURN_CD := v_Return_Cd;
        O_RETURN_MSG := v_Return_Msg;

        RETURN;
END; 

$function$;
```

Comment: Also add what the function is suppose to do, what it is doing right now.

Comment: it is working...

Comment: What error are you getting?  Or does it spit out garbage?  People can't help you if you don't explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the wrong exception.

Thete is no function `to_timestamp` with a single `bpchar` argument, and *that* rather than a conversion error causes an exception.

You should use `WHEN data_exception` rather than `WHEN OTHERS`.